# How to use an AngularJS controller from a controller.js file in html code

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to use a controller that I wrote and saved in a controller.js file, but it won't work in my html code. I have the code written as: (This is the version that doesn't work correctly)

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="movieCtrl">
   ..bit of my html code..
</div>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

This version however works just fine:

```
<div ng-app"myApp" ng-controller="movieCtrl">
      irrelavent html code here
</div>
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('movieCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.$watch('search', function() {
        fetch();
    });

    $scope.search = "tt2975590";

    function fetch() {
        $http.get("http:www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + $scope.search + "&plot=full&r=json")
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.details = response.data;
            });
    }

    $scope.update = function(movie) {
        $scope.search = movie.Title;
    }
});
</script>
```

How do I get it to work with the controller in its own controller.js file?

Comment: Please, provide the controller code.

Comment: And... Maybe your src attribute has the wrong address.

Comment: How would I fix that? And there shouldn't be anything wrong with my controller code, as the code works perfectly when in the index.html file, but not when I try to put it in its own controller.js file and load it into the html code with <script src="controller.js"></script>

Comment: In what folder is in it?

Comment: I am only working on the controller, so its a very small and simple folder set up. I have a main project folder, and then the index.html file is in there, with another folder in there called controllers for the controller.js file

Comment: /controllers/controller.js

Comment: Still didn't fix the problem

Comment: Could you try to show the files structure?

Comment: And your script should be loaded after the angularjs one.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean exactly with the last comment. And the file structure is just:
-app/
     index.html
     -controllers/
            controller.js

Comment: Try ../controllers/controller.js

Comment: Did it work? The .. Means "go back to parent path then star the path from there."

Comment: Nope, still nothing. I am unsure why it is not working right. I am going to edit the original question to try and make it a little more clear what the issue is

Comment: Ok. I'll try to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the original post to try and make it as clear as i could

Comment: That's the thing. If this is working like this, it should work in an external file. I really think there is something wrong I the path you used in the src attribute.

Comment: Root/app/index.html  And root/controllers/controller.js    Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like how I have the files structured

Comment: So try ../controllers/controller.js and the see in the browser if there is a 404 for file not found error in the console.

Comment: You are amazing. I never knew there was a console you could open in a web browser like that lol I used the console to trouble shoot the path in the src attribute, I needed to add one my file name in the path, so it was actually ../app/controllers/controller.js That worked perfectly, thank you so much

Comment: Did it work? Yes, press f12 when in the browser.

Comment: I'll post the answer then.

Comment: Yeah, it worked perfectly. I just had to alter what you said to try and add another directory to the beginning of the path in the src attribute, since the controller.js file is in app/controllers/controller.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as discussed, the problem was the relative path.
Solution:
Change the src attribute to "../app/controllers/controller.js".

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't working because you have a syntax error here `ng=controller="movieCtrl"`.

It should be `ng-controller="movieCtrl"`

I am assuming the rest of your code is correct. If that is right, then this change should fix your problems.

Comment: that was just a typo when typing it up here, i do actually have it as ng-controller in my code

Comment: Then please provide more code because there is nothing wrong with what you have posted. What have you named the angular module when you declared it? Are you sure the script is being loaded? Also make sure the name of your controller is correct.

Comment: var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('movieCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.$watch('search', function() {
  fetch();
 });

 $scope.search = "tt2975590";

 function fetch() {
  $http.get("http:www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + $scope.search + "&plot=full&r=json")
   .then(function(response) {
    $scope.details = response.data;
   });
 }
});

Comment: I think the path to your controller.js file is wrong. But I am not for sure. What is the file structure of your project?

Comment: That is my code for the controller, which works perfectly fine if I put it directly into the html code inside the <script></script> but doesn't work if it has its own file named controller.js and is loaded into it in the code <script src="controller.js"></script>

Comment: I am basically just working on a controller, so I just have the main project folder, and then I have the index.html in that, with a folder for controllers with controller.js in that

Comment: Is it possible to post a jsfiddle or link to the project. Because I do not know what is wrong if your file structure is the way you say it is.

Comment: No idea how I would do that. I am very new to html and angularjs, just started learning basics of it last week on my own

Comment: I included all the relevant code, the missing parts don't matter as they shouldn't affect whether or not the controller works in its own file or not

Comment: You did not include any relevant code in your question. I would like to see all the code for each file in the project since it is a very small project. I can't help you any further without it.

Comment: That is all the relevant code, all the other code is just the basic <body></body> and such tags for the basic html code and then inside the <div> tag is some irrelavent code to the controller working

Comment: The code posted in the original question is in the index.html file and is the only relevant code, and then the controller code (which isn't relevant to the controller not working in its own file but working in the html code in the script tags) is like the third comment

Answer (score 0):

You didn't instantiate your controller properly in your HTML code.

Here is a much cleaner solution that works. Remember to change `ng=controller` to `ng-controller` in your html code.

**HTML Markup**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="movieCtrl">
     //bit of html and Angular code such as...
     <input type="text" ng-model="watchInput" Placeholder="Type Something"/>
     <p>{{watchInput}}</p> 
</div>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

**Controller** in `controller.js`

Your AngularJS Controller should look something like...

```
myApp = angular.module ("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("movieCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  //Your Controller code goes here
}]);
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know.

Comment: That was just a typo when typing it here, I do have it correct in my code as ng-controller. What you wrote looks almost identical to the code I wrote for the controller.js file